# How do I rename a container folder in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a folder in github that contains my application and I would like to rename it and I have been using the following codes to try to change the name but I am not sure how to use it

Commands use:

```
git mv \E:\Trabajo\LakiyEarth\lakiy-earth \E:\Trabajo\LakiyEarth\Lakiy
git mv lakiy-earth Lakiy
```

[folder I want to rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amEge.png)

Comment: this can be done without git. why use `git mv`?

Comment: @LeiYang 
so that it recognizes me as a change in git and so I change the name of the folder in the repository

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git` commands only inside the repository (folder). If you want to move or rename the folder itself, use a simple `mv`. Git doesn't know or care about its name.

Comment: it did not work friend, try the following ways and I throw the following errors:
`code`
$ mv lakiy-earth Lakiy
mv: cannot stat 'lakiy-earth': No such file or directory                  
`code`
`code`
$ mv \E:\Trabajo\LakiyEarth\lakiy-earth\E:\Trabajo\LakiyEarth\Lakiy
mv: cannot stat 'E:TrabajoLakiyEarthLakiy2': No such file or directory
`code`

Comment: @Guayavas what shell are you using? Backslashes are used for escaping on *nix systems so you could try replacing them with forward slashes but it depends on your environment

Answer (score 1):

Tried it to do it through git CLI commands, but since its the top-most folder to be changed, faced some trouble because to use git commands there must be `.git` folder which will be within the folder, not anywhere outside. Hence tried to use the repo's UI page to change the name of the folder. In my case of Gitlab, navigated to `Settings -> General -> Advanced -> Change path` to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can't be achieved using `git mv` since it's already outside the scope of git for that project. What you want though is to rename your repo in github/gitlab. Then copy the new repo url.

Then inside your app directory, update the remote url to point to your new repo

```
git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here
```

Git doesn't really care if your app directory is the same as the repo name. So outside of your app directory, you can do a regular `mv`. Like so:

```
mv old-dirname new-dirname
```

Comment: If sorry, I had not realized that I had written wrong, I had already tried before and it did not work, it throws me the same error:
fatal: 'E:TrabajoLakiyEarthlakiy-earth' is outside repository at 'E:/Trabajo/Lakiy/Lakiy2'

Comment: And well, if it is obviously outside the repository, because it is this same folder that contains the repository that I want to change the name of

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question but I get what you want now, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic rename (or move):

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
```

…followed by commit and push would be the simplest way to rename a directory in a git repo.

Reference: https://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/rename-files-and-folders-with-git

Comment: Thanks for the information but it didn't work, since what I want to do is change the name of the container folder and not the name of a folder within it;
Since I want git to recognize this as a change and when doing a push it modifies the name of the containing folder in gitlab

Comment: you are not able to change it directly? right click on folder and rename it, does that causes any problem?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the container directory is created based on the repository's url. For example if the url is `https://git.com/my-project` the container directory will be named `my-project`.

To change the url on gitlab, you need to navigate to `Settings -> General -> Advanced` within the project and change it in the `Rename repository` section.

You’ll then need to update that repository locally with the new location once you’ve done by running

`git remote set-url origin https://git.com/my-renamed-project`

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `git`, only use `mv`

```
mv oldname newname
```

You must be in the folder that contains the folder you're renaming.

Comment: As Jan Wilamowski said over a year ago. Please don't repeat answers.